# Issues connecting with MongoDB Atlas from Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have recently came across mongoDB Atlas so i'm not really familiar with it. I followed the necessary procedure to set it up and tried linking my Node.js code to it. This is how I attempted to connect:

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

const db = require("./config/keys").mongoURI;

mongoose.connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
    .then(() => console.log("MongoDB successfully connected"))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server up and running on port ${port} !`));
```

The mongoURI is stored in the config/keys.js file. I am sure that it is correct.

This is the following error that I receive every time I use nodemon to run it:

```
MongooseError [MongooseServerSelectionError]: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/.
    at new MongooseServerSelectionError (/Users/Desktop/SEMESTER 2/Dummy/Server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/serverSelection.js:24:11)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/Users/Desktop/SEMESTER 2/Dummy/Server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:823:32)
    at Mongoose.connect (/Users/Desktop/SEMESTER 2/Dummy/Server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:333:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Desktop/SEMESTER 2/Dummy/Server/server.js:10:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    setName: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    servers: Map(3) {
      'dummy-shard-00-01-3gxsb.gcp.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'dummy-shard-00-02-3gxsb.gcp.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'dummy-shard-00-00-3gxsb.gcp.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    compatibilityError: null,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    commonWireVersion: null
  },
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}
```

I have already changed my list of IP addresses to include every IP address, it still doesn't work.

Do you guys know what is resulting in this?

Found the reason why: Turns out the wifi I was connected to while trying to connect with MongoDB Atlas doesn't allow outbound connections to port 27017. I tried using other sources of wifi and it resolved the issue.

Comment: _Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/._

Comment: i have in fact made it accessible for all IP addresses: (0.0.0.0/0  (includes your current IP address)). It still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you connect from that same machine using something else, like mongo shell or telnet?

Comment: I tried mongo shell and mongo compass, nothing works.

Comment: Resolved the issue already, included the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

I am writing this for helping others to save there time because I already wasted my time for solving this issues.
If you feel that your code is totally correct then also not connecting ,
**THE BASIC SETTINGs YOU HAVE TO DO**

1. In Mongodb Atlas see if your network access is your IP address or prefer
   allow access to all.

---

2.Check in Built in role that you selected admin option.

---

3.Do check if you are not connected to any VPN because while making cluster you
choose different country.

---

4.Make sure your connection string is in this format
"*mongodb+srv://**yourid**:**password**@cluster0.0q8wi.mongodb.net/**databasename*"**

---

5. Make sure you read and obey the commands according to documentations given
   by the frameworks like Mongoose,Node.js,Express etc.

---

6.Dont do more than one connection for the first time.